# Schedule tasks not executing in docker containers

Tags: docker, azure-devops, containers, scheduled-tasks, docker-swarm

I have a physical server running a bunch of scheduled tasks. I need to run it in the docker container instead.
Can anyone help me with this?

this is my docker file

```
FROM MyOrganization/dockerdev.azurecr.io/images/base/2019/windows-aspnet:20210614.1

COPY . /web-app

COPY ScheduledTasks.ps1 /

RUN C:\ScheduledTasks.ps1


ENTRYPOINT "C:\ScheduledTasks.ps1"
```

and this is my schedule task that i need to run in docker container

(ScheduledTask.ps1)

"SubMgr DTS Audience Sync"
12:00 AM Every Day
SubMgrJobs.exe -a

$action  = New-ScheduledTaskAction -WorkingDirectory 'C:\web-app' -Execute 'SubMgr.Jobs.exe' -Argument '-a'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 12am
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "SubMgr Audience Sync" -User SYSTEM

"SubMgr DTS Center Sync"
12:00 AM Every Day
SubMgrJobs.exe --plantInfoProcess

$action  = New-ScheduledTaskAction -WorkingDirectory 'C:\web-app' -Execute 'SubMgr.Jobs.exe' -Argument '--plantInfoProcess'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 12am
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "SubMgr Center Sync" -User SYSTEM

"SubMgr DTS Client Sync"
02:00 PM Every Day - After triggered, repeast every 02:00:00 for a duration of 1 day
SubMgrJobs.exe -s full-etl

$action  = New-ScheduledTaskAction -WorkingDirectory 'C:\web-app' -Execute 'SubMgr.Jobs.exe' -Argument '-s full-etl'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 10am -RepetitionInterval (New-Timespan -Hours 4) -RepetitionDuration (New-Timespan -Days 1)
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "SubMgr Client Sync" -User SYSTEM

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your schedule task as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Very likely there is no scheduler running inside the container. The container is basically just one process. If that were the scheduler your application would not run. So if you want both, ensure you have the entrypoint launch both of them and not terminate until both are finished.

Comment: I am very new to Azure DevOps and the docker world, how do id do it exactly?

Comment: One way to fix it is to run a whole OS in docker (FROM centos). Then services like cron should be available, at least installable. Some people may argue that this would be a heavy weight container and try to find smaller solutions.